# Multiple plugins files with same module dependecy intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, plugins, spigot

i have created a core module in IntelliJ (Community Edition) to setup easily my plugins(Minecraft) and do not re-write every Util class.

I have encountered a few problems:

Let's say i have 2 plugins, called Plugin1 and Plugin2, both import the MyCoreAPI module.

if i build both plugins(one and two), adding the MyCoreAPI as compile output in the artifacts and then modify something, let's say remove a method inside MyCoreAPI. I have to rebuild both Plugins because they have the same module dependecy with same package.

Is there a way to mirror or to make a clone with different package for each Plugin project?
example: instead of being me.mrbast.mycoreapi for both plugins, it becomes me.mrbast.PluginOne.mycoreapi and me.mrbast.PluginTwo.mycoreapi.

Comment: Maven is a build system to manage dependencies.   It can be a bit hard to setup for the first time, but it will be worthwhile.

Comment: @JustanotherJavaprogrammer do maven works locally? also, can i mirror a whole project and change it's package?

Comment: I can work locally, however it is not ideal. You will create modules of your code and maven ensures the current version is used when built.